# How to insert List <Products> into database

Tags: java, mysql, list, jdbc

I am new to Java. I have created a generic list of Products type ,how can I add it into the database. The list contains objects of Products, and columns in the database are fields of Products class. Even if I separate the list by listvariable.get(0) and so on, I get the object, not the values inside that objects.

UPDATE :  Inserted using for loop and getting fields for each objects. Is there any  better way

```
import java.util.*;
public class Products {

    public static List <Products> li  = new ArrayList<Products> ();

    static 
    {
        Products o = new Products (1,"Milky Way",12.0,7);   // Static because  
        Products o1 = new Products (2,"Dairy Milk",50.0,17); // these entries 
        Products o2 = new Products (3,"Borunville",70.0,27);  // are mandatory
        Products o3 = new Products (4,"Lindt",1022.0,107);
        li.add(o);
        li.add(o1);
        li.add(o2);
        li.add(o3);
    }
    int ItemCode;
    String ItemName;
    double UnitPrice;
    int AvailableCount; 
    public int v=3;

    Products()
    {}

    Products (int x,String y, double c, int d)
    {
        ItemCode=x;
        ItemName=y;
        UnitPrice=c;
        AvailableCount=d;

    }
    public String toString ()       
    {

        return (  ItemName+" "+ ItemCode +" "+ UnitPrice + " "+ AvailableCount);
    }
    void addProduct()
    {
        li.add(this);
    }

    public List <Products> initProducts()       

    {                   return li;
    }

}

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class Shopowner {



    public static void main (String ...args)

    { 

        Products o = new Products(6,"Eclairs",12.33,5);
        o.addProduct();

    System.out.println(new Products().initProducts());



    try
    {
        Connectivity.establishConnection(); // static method for db url and drivers

         for (int i =0;i<4;i++)
    {
        Products x=Products.li.get(i);

        String name=x.ItemName;
        int id= x.ItemCode;
        int count =x.AvailableCount;
        double price = x.UnitPrice;
        PreparedStatement stm = Connectivity.con.prepareStatement("insert into Products_tbl values (?,?,?,?)");
        stm.setInt(1, id);
        stm.setString(2, name);
        stm.setDouble(3,price);
    stm.setInt(4, count);
    stm.executeUpdate();
    }



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}  

    //System.out.println(new Products().li);


    }
}
```

Comment: I can see 3 questions. 1) How to insert 2) How to get values and 3) How to improve code (and what do you mean by that?) Maybe you should just solve one problem at a time.

Comment: I can get values from the list, printing the objects and over riding toString method would suffice. My question is how to insert the list into database. And it never hurts to get some good suggestions from people who have experience :)

Comment: My first suggestion would be to create `getItemCode()` etc methods that return the values of each `Products` object. Take a look at this example: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

Comment: The Java Persistence API (JPA) is used to persist objects into a database. Its as nice api that does a lot of work for you. Your objects (Products and Shopowner) map directly to the database. So your getters and setters can be used to get and set objects in the database. Check it out

Comment: PreparedStatement stm = Connectivity.con.prepareStatement("insert into Products_tbl values (?,?,?,?)"); can be moved outside loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use batch insert in this manner:

---

```
try {
  connection con.setAutoCommit(false);        
  PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(    
    "insert into product(code,name,price,available) values (?,?,?,?");
  Iterator<Product> it = li.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext()){
     Product p = it.next();
    prepStmt.setString(1,p.getCode());            
    prepStmt.setString(2,p.getCode());
    prepStmt.setInt(3,p.getPrice());
    prepStmt.setBoolean(4,p.isAvailable());
    prepStmt.addBatch();                      

  }      
  int [] numUpdates=prepStmt.executeBatch();
  for (int i=0; i < numUpdates.length; i++) {
    if (numUpdates[i] == -2)
      System.out.println("Execution " + i + 
        ": unknown number of rows updated");
    else
      System.out.println("Execution " + i + 
        "successful: " + numUpdates[i] + " rows updated");
  }
  con.commit();
} catch(BatchUpdateException b) {
  // process BatchUpdateException
}
```