# How do I update thousands of records into MySQL DB in milliseconds

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to update about 10K records into MySQL DB in less than a second. I have written below code which takes about 6-8 seconds to update a list of records into DB.

```
public void updateResultList(List<?> list) {
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "root";
            String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://12.1.1.1/db_1?useSSL=false";
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            PreparedStatement pstm = null;

            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
                Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass);
                myConn.setAutoCommit(false);
                for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                    Object[] row = (Object[]) list.get(i);
                    int candidateID = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(row[0]));
                    String result = String.valueOf(row[14]);
                    int score = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(row[19]));
                    String uploadState = (String) row[20];

                    String sql = "UPDATE personal_info SET result = ?, score = ?, uploadState = ? "
                                + " WHERE CandidateID = ?";

                    pstm = (PreparedStatement) myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    pstm.setString(1, result);
                    pstm.setInt(2, score);
                    pstm.setString(3, uploadState);
                    pstm.setInt(4, candidateID);
                    pstm.addBatch();
                    pstm.executeBatch();

                }
                myConn.commit();
                myConn.setAutoCommit(true);
                pstm.close();
                myConn.close();

            }
            catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    throw new ServletException(exc);
                } catch (ServletException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
       }
```

Please let me know your inputs to optimize this code for performance improvement.

Comment: Try calling `executeBatch()` after the `for` loop.

Comment: I had tried calling it outside for loop but it was updating the last record only.

Comment: Why are you setting autoCommit to true after committing?

Comment: Because I set it to false initially, so then making it to default as true in the end.

Comment: But ... why?  The next thing you do is close the connection.  Setting it to the "default" is pointless.

Comment: ok, I made the changes. Any other changes in the code to make the update to db faster? It is taking about 6-8 seconds and I want to reduce it to less than a second.

Comment: OK ... which changes?

Comment: I removed 'setAutoCommit(true)' and placed 'pstm.executeBatch();' outside for loop but it is updating only last record in the db.

Comment: You also need to move the `pstm = (PreparedStatement) myConn.prepareStatement(sql);` out of the loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than batching the individual UPDATEs, you could batch INSERTs into a temporary table with `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` and then use a single UPDATE statement to update the main table. On my machine with a local MySQL instance, the following code takes about 2.5 seconds ...

```java
long t0 = System.nanoTime();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

String sql = null;
sql = "UPDATE personal_info SET result=?, score=?, uploadState=? WHERE CandidateID=?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
String tag = "X";
for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
    ps.setString(1, String.format("result_%s_%d", tag, i));
    ps.setInt(2, 200000 + i);
    ps.setString(3, String.format("state_%s_%d", tag, i));
    ps.setInt(4, i);
    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
System.out.printf("%d ms%n", (System.nanoTime() - t0) / 1000000);
```

... while this version takes about 1.3 seconds:

```java
long t0 = System.nanoTime();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

String sql = null;
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (CandidateID INT, result VARCHAR(255), score INT, uploadState VARCHAR(255))");
sql = "INSERT INTO tmp (result, score, uploadState, CandidateID) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
String tag = "Y";
for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
    ps.setString(1, String.format("result_%s_%d", tag, i));
    ps.setInt(2, 400000 + i);
    ps.setString(3, String.format("state_%s_%d", tag, i));
    ps.setInt(4, i);
    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
sql = 
          "UPDATE personal_info pi INNER JOIN tmp ON tmp.CandidateID=pi.CandidateID "
        + "SET pi.result=tmp.result, pi.score=tmp.score, pi.uploadState=tmp.uploadState";
st.execute(sql);
conn.commit();
System.out.printf("%d ms%n", (System.nanoTime() - t0) / 1000000);
```

Comment: This is the best solution so far. It took 1234 ms for uploading 2000 records. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to init `prepareStatement` only once,you need to init it before the `for` loop

Second,you should avoid excute `pstm.executeBatch();` for every loop it will cost much more resource,you need to execute it for a specified amount,such as 100,500 or more,also do not execute it outside the `for` loop for only once,due to it will cost more memory resource

```
Class.forName(driver);
Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass);
myConn.setAutoCommit(false);
String sql = "UPDATE personal_info SET result = ?, score = ?, uploadState = ? "
                + " WHERE CandidateID = ?";
pstm = (PreparedStatement) myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    Object[] row = (Object[]) list.get(i);
    int candidateID = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(row[0]));
    String result = String.valueOf(row[14]);
    int score = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(row[19]));
    String uploadState = (String) row[20];
    pstm.setString(1, result);
    pstm.setInt(2, score);
    pstm.setString(3, uploadState);
    pstm.setInt(4, candidateID);
    pstm.addBatch();
    if(i%500==0){//execute when it meet a specified amount
        pstm.executeBatch();
    }
}
pstm.executeBatch();
myConn.commit();
myConn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, this has helped to reduce some time. Still it is taking somewhere around 5 seconds to update 2000 records.

Comment: 500 might be not suitable ,you need to test for.a more suitable count

Answer (score 1):

your `pstm.executeBatch()` should be after `for`loop

refer [How to insert List  into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134561/how-to-insert-list-products-into-database)

Comment: This is updating only last record into the DB.

Comment: @JayeshB - I think you are mistaken.  Try doing it again.  And remove the unnecessary `setAutoCommit(true)` at the end.