# Error while using multiple update statements in iBatis

Tags: mysql, xml, spring-boot, mybatis, ibatis

I am executing multiple update statements under `<foreach>` tag. The queries seem to be working fine while executing in MySQL workbench. But while running through springboot application, I am facing an error as follows:

**Update.xml**

```
<update id="saveSeats" parameterType="map" useGeneratedKeys="true">
        <foreach collection="seats" item="seat" separator=";">
            UPDATE t002_seat_mst SET IS_ASSIGNED=#{seat.isAssigned},TEAM_ID=#{seat.team.teamId} WHERE (SEAT_ID=#{seat.seatId} AND MAP_ID=#{mapId})
        </foreach>;
    </update>
```

**Error log**

```
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE t002_seat_mst SET IS_ASSIGNED=1,TEAM_ID=31 WHERE (SEAT_ID=677 AND MAP_ID=' at line 1
### The error may exist in config/SeatsMapper.xml
### The error may involve com.seat.arrangement.dao.mapper.MapMapper.saveSeats-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: UPDATE t002_seat_mst SET IS_ASSIGNED=?,TEAM_ID=? WHERE (SEAT_ID=? AND MAP_ID=?) ; UPDATE t002_seat_mst SET IS_ASSIGNED=?,TEAM_ID=? WHERE (SEAT_ID=? AND MAP_ID=?) ; UPDATE t002_seat_mst SET IS_ASSIGNED=?,TEAM_ID=? WHERE (SEAT_ID=? AND MAP_ID=?) ;
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE t002_seat_mst SET IS_ASSIGNED=1,TEAM_ID=31 WHERE (SEAT_ID=677 AND MAP_ID=' at line 1
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE t002_seat_mst SET IS_ASSIGNED=1,TEAM_ID=31 WHERE (SEAT_ID=677 AND MAP_ID=' at line 1] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE t002_seat_mst SET IS_ASSIGNED=1,TEAM_ID=31 WHERE (SEAT_ID=677 AND MAP_ID=' at line 1
```

Comment: You should perform proper batch operation instead of putting multiple statements in a single statement. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58914577/).

Comment: The batch operation to be performed in @configuration class?

Comment: It's usually in the service layer or in a DAO class. See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/spring/sqlsession.html) for how to prepare/use a batch `SqlSession`.

Comment: Hi ave, I have solved this by allowing mutli queries in my URL. `?allowMultiQueries=true`

Comment: Allowing multi queries is OK when 1) you don't need the number of affected rows and 2) there are not many items in `seats`. :)

Comment: I have around 230 rows under `seats`. And as I can see it is taking a lot to update? Can it be solved using batch operations?

Comment: It's hard to say (230 is not particularly large), but it seems to be worth a try. With MySQL, there also is another [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50819641) that could improve performance.

Comment: The technique you mentioned is using JDBC. How can I execute using mybatis?

Comment: Here is an executable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-60993091). If you use the INSERT-then-UPDATE approach, be sure to enable [`rewriteBatchedStatements`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

Comment: Thanks alot @ave

Comment: It is working very efficiently now.

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much for letting me know the result. :D